# Selecionar texto de uma div e ignorar qualquer outra tag usando o Xpath

Tags: php, xpath, php-domxpath

tenho a seguinte situação onde quero obter o texto de uma div e ignorar o conteúdo das divs filhas e obter somente o texto da div pai a baixo segue a estrutura do html.

```html
<div class="text-description">
    <div>
        <div class="ad text">
           conteudo a ser ignorado
        </div>
    </div>
    é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500
    <br>
    é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500
    <br>
    é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500
    <br>
</div>
```

estou usando a seguinte expressão xpath para obter esse texto

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes= $xpath->query("/html/body//div[@class='text-description']");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $text = $node->textContent;
}
```

logo o retorto que tenho e a captura de todo o texto incluindo todo o texto da div filha onde quero pegar somente o texto da div pai incluindo as tags br